# Do I need to get professional water damage repair, or can I handle this?

Tags: plumbing, water, wood, hardwood-floor, water-damage

We recently had a toilet overflow a bit. There was a small amount of waste in the water. The bathroom itself has tile floors, but the toilet is right next to a very thin wall. The room on the other side of that wall has hardwood floors.

We cleaned and disinfected the bathroom floor and immediately used towels to soak up most of the water, but the water made it to the molding/trim in the bathroom. Over the next couple of hours, we noticed a slight amount of cupping on the wooden floor next to the bathroom.

Do I need professionals to come out and figure this thing out? I'm worried about sanitation and mold, but I don't want to spend an arm and a leg if this is really not an issue. There has not been any visible damage on the ceiling of the level below this.

Here are some pics...

[The toilet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq38M.jpg)

[How close it is to the other room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTh3v.jpg)

[Cupping is very difficult to capture with a camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uknq2.jpg)

I think the water got under the wooden floor in between the bathroom and the room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let it dry for a week or 2 & if nothing's gotten worse & you're not even or barely noticing it with your feet then let it go. Tearing the floor up for a cup or 2 of water that's already gone isn't worth it.

If it actually bothers you later you can sand the cupping down & back to flat. You'll have to re-stain & re-polyurethane the area after that.

Every floor cups a tiny bit all over the place from humidity eventually & you may find some parts of the floor elsewhere are worse. Think of it as character.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Should I be concerned about the fact that there was a small amount of human waste in the water? The toilet was clogged slightly, and while no large chunks of waste came out of the toilet as it was overflowing, the water was not perfectly clean.

Comment: Only if you notice something unpleasant (husband's not included), but it's nothing harmful & your disinfecting probably got everything.

Comment: Gotcha. I was worried because I couldn't really sanitize anything that had gotten under the floorboards or behind the wall, but this is reassuring. I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem & best of luck that nothing gets nor smells worse.